# python pandas right fill values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replicate a "right fill" excel-like function which fills the values right till the next value is not null/nan/empty. This "right-fill" exercise is only to be done if the value in the immediate following row in not empty or "nan".
I have the following pandas dataframe dataset. My current input table is "have". My output table is "want".

```
import pandas as pd
have = pd.DataFrame({ \
"0": pd.Series(["abc","1","something here"]) \
,"1": pd.Series(["","2","something here"]) \
,"2": pd.Series(["","3","something here"]) \
,"3": pd.Series(["something","1","something here"]) \
,"4": pd.Series(["","2","something here"]) \
,"5": pd.Series(["","","something here"]) \
,"6": pd.Series(["","","something here"]) \
,"7": pd.Series(["cdf","5","something here"]) \
,"8": pd.Series(["","6","something here"]) \
,"9": pd.Series(["xyz","1","something here"]) \
})

want = pd.DataFrame({ \
"0": pd.Series(["abc","1","something here"]) \
,"1": pd.Series(["abc","2","something here"]) \
,"2": pd.Series(["abc","3","something here"]) \
,"3": pd.Series(["something","1","something here"]) \
,"4": pd.Series(["something","2","something here"]) \
,"5": pd.Series(["","","something here"]) \
,"6": pd.Series(["","","something here"]) \
,"7": pd.Series(["cdf","5","something here"]) \
,"8": pd.Series(["cdf","6","something here"]) \
,"9": pd.Series(["xyz","1","something here"]) \
})
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a boolean mask on row 2.

- test if it's null (`None` or `np.nan`)
- test if it's equal to an empty string `''`

Assignment

- Use `loc` to assign
- `replace` forward fills nulls by default.

---

```
cond = have.loc[1].isnull() | have.loc[1].ne('')
have.loc[0, cond] = have.loc[0, cond].replace('', None)
have
```

[image]

---

If the blanks `''` are white space `' '` we can use `strip`

```
cond = have.loc[1].isnull() | have.loc[1].ne('')
have.loc[0, cond] = have.loc[0, cond].str.strip().replace('', None)
have
```